# Is there a way to run two loops (for loops ,while loops,....) in the same time?

Tags: python

Is there a way to run two loops (for loops, while loops,...) at the same time in Ppython? For a simple example I want to run two for loops in parallel (at the same time) not linearly (one after one). If that possible please show me for the loops in this script:

```
for x in range (0,10):
    print('hello world')
for x in range(0,10 ):
    print ('welcome to the world')
```

Comment: This seems like a common topic, have you done any research?

Comment: This is a pure conceptual questions. If you want really do parallel processing, you have to create processes or threads. If you want to do 2 thinks in synchronized loops, create only one loop and do the both tasks inside it.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to use numba :

```
@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def simulator(out):
    # iterate loop in parallel
    for i in prange(out.shape[0]):
        print('hello world')
        print('welcome to the world')
```

another way is to use asyncio but it is more complex to handle.